# How to separate image folder and css folder to work with eachother in maven project

Tags: css, image

I have  two CSS files and three images in my maven project. When I put the images in the CSS folder it's working fine but when I move the images to the image folder, those images will not been shown in the web page. I want to have a nice structure on my project and therefor an separate image folder. How can I do it? I think I need to do some changes in my CSS but don't know how and where. I don't know that much about CSS.

layout.css

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
   }
 body {
font:14px/1.3 Arial,sans-serif;
background-color:#212121;
}
header {
background-color:#212121;
box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px #111111;
color:#fff;
display:block;
height:70px;
position:relative;
width:100%;
z-index:100;
}
header h2{
font-size:22px;
font-weight:normal;
left:50%;
margin-left:-400px;
padding:22px 0;
position:absolute;
width:540px;
}
header a.stuts,a.stuts:visited{
border:none;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fcfcfc;
font-size:14px;
left:50%;
line-height:31px;
margin:23px 0 0 110px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
header .stuts span {
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-left:5px;
}
.container {
height: 571px;
margin: 30px auto;
width: 957px;
 }
```

and the menue.css

```
#nav,#nav ul {
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#nav {
background: url('menu_bg.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
clear: both;
font-size: 12px;
height: 58px;
padding: 0 0 0 9px;
position: relative;
width: 957px;
}
#nav ul {
background-color: #222;
border:1px solid #222;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
border-width: 0 1px 1px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
left: -9999px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
z-index: 2;

-moz-transform: scaleY(0);
-ms-transform: scaleY(0);
-o-transform: scaleY(0);
-webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
transform: scaleY(0);

-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;

-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.1s linear;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.1s linear;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.1s linear;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s linear;
transition: transform 0.1s linear;
}
#nav li {
background: url('menu_line.png') no-repeat scroll right 5px transparent;
float: left;
position: relative;
 }
#nav li a {
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
float: left;
font-weight: normal;
height: 30px;
padding: 23px 20px 0;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
#nav li:hover > a {
color: #00B4FF;
}
#nav li:hover, #nav a:focus, #nav a:hover, #nav a:active {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #121212;
outline: 0 none;
 }
#nav li:hover ul.subs {
left: 0;
top: 53px;
width: 180px;

-moz-transform: scaleY(1);
-ms-transform: scaleY(1);
-o-transform: scaleY(1);
-webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
transform: scaleY(1);
}
#nav ul li {
background: none;
width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li a {
float: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover > a {
background-color: #121212;
color: #00B4FF;
}
#lavalamp {
background: url('lavalamp.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 16px;
left: 13px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 64px;

-moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
-o-transition: all 300ms ease;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
transition: all 300ms ease;
}
 #lavalamp:hover {
-moz-transition-duration: 3000s;
-ms-transition-duration: 3000s;
-o-transition-duration: 3000s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 3000s;
transition-duration: 3000s;
}
#nav li:nth-child(1):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 13px;
}
#nav li:nth-child(2):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 90px;
}
#nav li:nth-child(3):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 170px;
}
#nav li:nth-child(4):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 250px;
 }
#nav li:nth-child(5):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 330px;
 }
#nav li:nth-child(6):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 410px;
}
#nav li:nth-child(7):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 490px;
}
#nav li:nth-child(8):hover ~ #lavalamp {
left: 565px;
 }
```

And finally index.jsp:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <header>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>

    </header>
    <div class="container">

        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a class="hsubs" href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="hsubs" href="#">Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2-8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="hsubs" href="#">Menu 3</a>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3-5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>

            <div id="lavalamp">
            </div>
        </ul>

     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And 3 images
       lavalamp.png,
       menu_bg.png,
       menu_line.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is with the way you are setting your paths. You are setting your image paths relative to your css files. Take a look at this [CSS paths](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) - I hope this is what you are looking for ^-^.

In case you want the quick and dirty version ->

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

> Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
>
> Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
>
> Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
> there (and so on...) To move forward, just start with the first > subdirectory and keep moving forward